# Changing and Saving Custom Culture After Its Registered

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization, cultureinfo

I recently registered a few custom cultures in ASP.NET and was asked later by our client to change something about one of them. For example, I registered `en-EU` which is a blanket "English for European Union" language-locale for English in the EU. I was asked to re-label it from European Union to just Europe. The Iso code `en-EU` will remain as it is, but I need to change the **English name** and **Native name** attributes from `English (European Union)` to `English (Europe)`. Can I do this without unregistering it and re-registering it? Will I lose content stored in this if I do have to unregister and re-register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like before you can register it again, it must have been unregistered (as [Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.register.aspx) throws an InvalidOperationException if the custom culture is already registered).

However what you can do is initialize your CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder from the existing custom culture, then de-register it (at this point you don't need it anymore), and then make your changes and register it again.

I.e. like this: (untested code)

```
  // Initalize the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder with en-EU
  CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder car = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("en-EU", 
                                         CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
  car.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-EU"));
  car.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo("en-EU"));

  // Unregister it
  CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Unregister("en-EU"); 

  // Update it
  car.CultureEnglishName = "English (European Union)";
  car.CultureNativeName = "English (Europe)";

  // Re-register it
  car.Register();
```